# uniform boundedness principle - problem with understanding proof

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm looking at the proof and there is a step I really don't get.

He states that for $\parallel x-x_0\parallel<\epsilon\Rightarrow \parallel T_\alpha x\parallel$, where $T_\alpha$ Is a bounded linear operator from a Banach to a normed space. Next for $y\neq0$ define $z=\frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}y+x_0\in B_\epsilon(x_0)$ and then holds:

$\frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}\parallel T_\alpha y\parallel-\parallel T_\alpha x_0\parallel\leq\parallel \frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}T_\alpha y+ T_\alpha x_0\parallel$. How does this estimation can be true changing the sign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you mean this $\frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}\parallel T_\alpha y\parallel-\parallel T_\alpha x_0\parallel\leq\parallel \frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}T_\alpha y+ T_\alpha x_0\parallel$ since you can't have a $y$ outside the norm and still have order.

Try this $\parallel \frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel} T_\alpha y\parallel$ = $\parallel \frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}T_\alpha y+ T_\alpha x_0 - T_\alpha x_0\parallel \leq$ $\parallel \frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}T_\alpha y+ T_\alpha x_0 \parallel$ + $\parallel -T_\alpha x_0\parallel$ = $\parallel \frac{\epsilon}{2\parallel y\parallel}T_\alpha y+ T_\alpha x_0 \parallel$ + $\parallel T_\alpha x_0\parallel$ and move the last one on the other side

Comment: Thanks... I didn't see it.

Comment: You 're welcome